# WooCommerce - Cart Widget - Fade out item on remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce for the first time on a project. I am just starting to learn JS and I never used AJAX before…

Right now I have a Cart Widget in my header, which is updating the total count, etc. if I remove or add items. I am using `<?php woocommerce_mini_cart() ?>` for this.

If items are removed from the cart widget, they just disappear. What I would like to have is this:

1. User clicks on the remove link
2. The product which will be removed fades out slowly
3. If there are more items in the cart widget, these items move (using transitions) up.
4. If there are no more items in the cart, the message "Your cart is empty" should fade in slowly.
5. The total count should fade out and fade in again with the new price

I am using the woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link from WooCommerce in my mini-cart.php, but changed `class="remove remove_from_cart_button"` to add my own script.

```
<?php
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
    '<a href="%s" class="sidecart-item-remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s">Aus dem Warenkorb entfernen</a>',
    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
    __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
    esc_attr( $product_id ),
    esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
), $cart_item_key );
?>
```

My products in the mini-cart are wrapped in this:

```
<div id="sidecart-item-id-<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>" class="sidecart-item sidecart-item-<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>" product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product_id ); ?>">
<div class="sidecart-item-wrapper sidecart-item-wrapper-<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>" data-cart_item_key="<?php echo esc_attr( $cart_item_key ); ?>">
```

What I have done so far:

```
/** 
 * Item removed from sidecart
 */

$(document).on( 'click', '.sidecart-item-remove', function(e) {

    $.fade_out_subtotal();
    e.preventDefault();

    var cart_item_key = $(this).attr( 'data-cart_item_key' );


        setTimeout(function(){
            // Need a (AJAX?) function here to remove product
            $('#sidecart-item-id-'+cart_item_key).fadeOut(1000);
            $.fade_in_subtotal();
        },500);

    console.log('Item removed from sidecart');

});


/**
 * Fade in/out subtotal in sidecart
 */

$.fade_out_subtotal = function(){

    $('.sidecart-subtotal-amount').fadeOut(1000);
}
$.fade_in_subtotal = function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sidecart-subtotal-amount').fadeIn(1000);
    },1000);
}
```

What is happening: Subtotal amount fades in and out, but there is a function missing to update the amount. The div for sidecart-item-id-* fades out and is removed. Well, it is not really removed. If I refresh the site. The products are back in the cart. Is the `cart_item_key` wrong? Where can I find the function WooCommerce is using to remove products?

Can someone please give me a hint on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.